# Vue js - Data from post request will not render

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the next vue instance:

```
 var immobles_destacats = ($('#immobles_destacats').length > 0) ? new Vue({
  el: '#immobles_destacats',
  data: {
    immobles: {}
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(i) {
      if (this.immobles[i].imatges.lenght == this.immobles[i].counter) {
        return this.immobles[i].counter = 0;
      }
      return this.immobles[i].counter++;
    },
    substract: function(i) {
      if (this.immobles[i].counter == 0) {
        return this.immobles[i].counter = this.immobles[i].imatges.lenght;
      }
      return this.immobles[i].counter--;
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    $.post('get_immobles_destacats', function(immobles, textStatus, xhr) {
      for (var i = 0; i < immobles.length; i++) {
        immobles_destacats.immobles[i] = immobles[i];
        immobles_destacats.immobles[i].counter = 0;
      }
    });
  }
}) : null;
```

And the next html to render the data 'immobles':

```
<div id="immobles_destacats">
    <div v-for="(immoble, key) in immobles" class="immoble"><img v-bind:src="immoble.imatges[immoble.counter].url"/>
      <input type="button" v-on:click="add(key)" value="+"/>
      <input type="button" v-on:click="substract(key)" value="-"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see, I set the data 'immobles' in the mounted function and I get this:
[image: google chrome Vue DevTools extension on the loaded page]
The problem comes when the page is loaded nothing is rendered, is it because the data 'immobles' doesn't trigger "onchange-renderhtml" when it's filled in the post request? if so, how can I set this "onchange-renderhtml" to the data 'immobles'?

Comment: have you tried `Vue.set`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on a stroke of luck, I still don't know why this wasn't working but the point is that now it does, this is the new Vue instance:

```
var immobles_destacats = ($('#immobles_destacats').length > 0) ? new Vue({
  el: '#immobles_destacats',
  data: {
    immobles: []
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(i) {
      alert(this.immobles[i].imatges.lenght)
      alert(this.immobles[i].counter)
      if (this.immobles[i].imatges.lenght == this.immobles[i].counter) {
        return this.immobles[i].counter = 0;
      }
      return this.immobles[i].counter++;
    },
    substract: function(i) {
      alert(this.immobles[i].counter)
      if (this.immobles[i].counter == 0) {
        return this.immobles[i].counter = this.immobles[i].imatges.lenght;
      }
      return this.immobles[i].counter--;
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    $.post('get_immobles_destacats', function(immobles, textStatus, xhr) {
      for (var i = 0; i < immobles.length; i++) {
        immobles[i].counter = 0;
        immobles_destacats.immobles.push(immobles[i]);
      }
    });
  }
}) : null;
```

Notice that now I push the object and I set the counter before pushing it.
Also, data 'immobles' is now an array, not an object